# Customized Solr Ranking by product of score and other fields

Tags: solr, rank

Solr can show the query score of each documents by field 'score'. I have two special fileds, say A and B. How can I rank the results based on product of score, A and B. I try to use something like **?q=data&sort=product(score, A, B) desc** but always get an error "Can't determine Sort Order: 'product(score, A, B) desc', pos=14"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting on score is default.
So you could boost this result by boosting on field A and B.
Take a look at this: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/search/BoostQParserPlugin.html
(nearly) something like this, if you search for foo (not tested)

```
{!boost b=product(A,B)}foo
```

Comment: So if I user {!boost b=product(A,B)}, does it have same effect like my formula score*A*B ? How can I implement even more complex formula, like sqrt(score)*log(A)*log(B)